# What is significance of "Person-Group" in Microsoft Cognitive service Face API?

Tags: face-detection, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using Microsoft Cognitive service Face API for face detection. While Working I see we need to create person group and creating person group is mandatory for identifying person. I check about the "Person-Group" a lot but didn't get anything. Can you please help me out to know what's the actual use & significance of "Person-Group".

Comment: I see this is you first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can we can understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers.

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix basically this is a theoretical question and the support person for this get it easily about what  am talking. Not sure what else I need to give here.

Answer (score 1):

For face identification/verification, you scope the search to the set of `Person` objects.  This set is called a `PersonGroup`.  In computer vision terms, the `PersonGroup` is the image classifier unit, and is trained from the faces of the `Person` objects contained therein.